# Local SSH incredibly slow when internet enabled (Vagrant / Laravel Homestead)

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I've installed and setup Laravel Homestead using Vagrant and Virtualbox successfully on my Mac. However, it takes around 20 seconds to ssh in (using `vagrant ssh` and `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1`...) and even longer to issue commands (30s - 1m!)

The peculiar problem is that as soon as I disable my Mac's internet connection, the SSH becomes lightening quick and I can login and issue commands in milliseconds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like VirtualBox issue rather Vagran's fault. NAT network (port forwarding in Vagrant) in VirtualBox can cause lots of weird issues.
I suggest you to:

1. Try update VirtualBox to latest version to see if this helped
2. If problem remains, configure Vagrant to user private_network and ssh via machine's IP and not the localhost (port forwarding).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "127.0.0.10"` to my config and it's sped up the SSH. Thank you! However, loading the webpages from the VM is still slow

Comment: @daveyWavey try to install newer versions of Vagrant and VirtualBox. I have similar issues and upgrading solved it.

I'm using Vagrant 1.7.4 https://bintray.com/mitchellh/vagrant/vagrant/1.7.4/view#files

VirtualBox 5.0.11 r104456 https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-5.0.11-104456-OSX.dmg